# Is the grand sum of the matrix products of two integer sequences useful in any particular way?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\bf A$, and $\bf B$, be square matrices of dimension $k$, that we populate with a sequence of integers according to an arithmetic progression of step $d$, in the case of $\bf A$, and step $D$ in the case of $\bf B$.

Let **M**, be the starting value for matrix **A**, and **N**, be the starting value for matrix **B**.  We enter each value as the respective top left corner element of its assigned matrix, and let the independent sequences propagate under the progressions from left to right, row by row, until completion bottom right.

For any choice of ***k***, **M**, **d**, **N**, and **D**, it is possible to perform matrix multiplication of **AB**, "*quickly*".  What I am interested to know is whether or not there is any value in being able to calculate the grand sum of the products matrix without having to compute the individual products themselves.  This can be done in a direct fashion and enables the summation to be quantified in terms of a quantity of cubes of the dimension ***k***, i.e. the total products value is determined as a whole or fractional amount of cubes.  These in turn may be converted to a quantity of squares of the dimension thereby giving the average value of the product elements.

Is anyone able to clarify if being able to perform such a set of operations "quickly", is useful in any context for sequences submitted to these procedures?

Edit 12/10/22

In response to the comment below the following information may be of interest.  For matrices constructed along the lines discussed, it *is* possible to perform normal ("dot product") multiplication in a way which seems to be completely ignored in a survey of the available literature.  This is to say, that normal matrix multiplication, or at least the goal of producing a products matrix, can be achieved much faster than might be supposed, by leveraging the structure of the arrangement of elements.  This does nothing to dispute the current bounds that apply to matrices composed of arbitrary elements.
What I would like to ascertain is whether or not matrix multiplication is ever considered to be a process that is applicable to integer sequences in the manner described.  For such arrangements ( and these are just one particular example of a *group* structure that I have investigated exhaustively), the actual elements of the  products matrix can be completely bypassed if the only thing we are interested in is the sum total of what all those product elements may be.

Comment: Could you elaborate on -- *For any choice of k, M, d, N, and D, it is possible to perform matrix multiplication of AB, "quickly"*?

Comment: @vvg To elaborate: once we have chosen a dimension k for the two matrices (e.g. k =5 gives us two square matrices, each comprising 25 elements), we may choose any integer value for each of the variables M, d, N, and D.  Some or all of the variables may be identical values, or they may all be completely different.

Comment: I MathJax'ed the first paragraph. Please MathJax the rest.

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo  I sincerely hope that my inability to comply with your request will not detract from the substance of the question I have posed.  MathJax, LaTeX, etc are not within my skill set.  I am able to illustrate the research I have conducted, but whether the format this will take will be an acceptable level of presentation to the community will have to be judged in due course.  What would be helpful to me is an understanding of whether what I am attempting to convey is simply trivial or of some interest to a more informed and inquisitive audience?

Comment: @b1tth1ck Why not read my revision in `Side-by-side Markdown` mode and learn some extremely basic MathJax? It takes 10 seconds. Matrices in `$\bf M$`. Reals in `$x$`.